# How do I get a count of fields with a specific value in JSON file with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I would like to get a count of how many times a specific value is listed in JSON file.  My ultimate goal is really to get a percentage.  But, I will start with just getting a count.  I am pretty sure I am making this harder than it really is, but I am new to bash and jq.

```
"fields": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "state": "complete",
          "substate": null,
          "exceptions": [],
          "name": "Sender Account Number",
          "output_name": null,
          "field_definition_attributes": {
            "required": false,
            "data_type": "Account Number",
            "multiline": false,
            "consensus_required": false,
            "supervision_override": null
          },
          "transcription": {
            "raw": "1685-0441-1",
            "normalized": "168504411",
            "source": "machine_transcription",
            "data_deleted": false,
            "user_transcribed": null,
            "row_index": null
          },
          "field_image_url": "/api/v4/image/be167a88-9d1d-43bc-82b2-3d96d8c06656?start_x=0.3110429607297866&start_y=0.1052441592299208&end_x=0.5696909842243418&end_y=0.16043316955780607"
        },
```

This is an example of my "fields" object in the JSON. I want to get a count of all the records that are "source": "machine_transcription",

I then should be able to calculate a percentage of the total.

Comment: what do you mean by all the records?

Comment: You're expected to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  The example above is just one section of my JSON to show structure.  The JSON has multiple FIELDS objects.  Of those there is a key called "source".  I want to count how many times the value "machine_transcription" shows up as a value in all the the FIELDS objects in the entire file.  Then, I would like to get the percentage based on the total amount of FIELDS.  Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @ wahiggins3, for your consideration for the updated requirement: here's an alternative solution based on a `walk-path` unix utility `jtc`: `<file.json jtc -x'<fields>l[:]' -y'<F>I1' -y'[source]:<machine_transcription><M>I1' -qqT'"{F}/{M}"' -x/-1 | bc -l`. Let me know if you like to elaborate on the tool usage in a separate answer. (PS. I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, it's unclear what you mean by `record` but the following jq-only solution (which assumes the input JSON is an object with a key named "fields" as shown in the question) should get you on your way. Notice that the output is a percentage.

```
def sigma( s ): reduce s as $x (0; . + $x);
def count( s ): sigma(if s then 1 else 0 end);

.fields
| length as $length
| count( .[]|.transcription.source == "machine_transcription" ) as $count
| if $length > 0 then $count*100/$length else null end
```

Answer (score -3):

You could pipe the output of jq to `grep` and then to `wc`:

```
curl example.com | jq | grep '"source": "machine_transcription"' | wc -l
```

this will output the number of lines containing the pattern `"source": "machine_transcription"`

Comment: The main disadvantage of a solution like this is that it will potentially produce the wrong result since the input might happen to contain this key/value pair outside `.fields`.

Comment: This may actually work because I could create a results set that will ensure that there is only one "source".  But the other comment is correct, if "source" was in another object in the JSON then it would return other values.